# How to use CHEF to run JAR?

Tags: java, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a working jar file on a ubuntu virtual machine. I need to create a Chef recipe to:

1. Execute jar - (eg:  run the command:  java -jar name.jar)
2. Stop the execution - when new jar is deployed.

Could it be achieved by CHEF?

Regards, 
Aditya Chaudhary

Comment: Q: Have you looked at any of the documentation?  For example: http://docs.getchef.com/resource_deploy.html.  Q: Are you saving the .pid of the process(es) you wish to restart?

Comment: I recently found the dropwizard cookbook. It runs as an executable jar and also sets up a service on the target server. You might be able to leverage this cookbook: https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/dropwizard

Comment: Looks valid to me... Helpful for me!! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of options out there. The simplest is probably:

```
execute "run file.jar in directory" do
  command "java -jar file.jar"
  cwd "directory containing jar file"
  action :run
end
```

The jar command will return an error code that Chef will use to determine success or failure. There are many ways to do this with Chef. You can see how others recommended running the jar command in the backround here if you need to move on after this command: [Jar execution in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414090/how-to-run-a-java-program-at-background-from-chef-recipe)

Comment: where i need to place my jar and yaml file inside cook book can please tell me the path .

Comment: Just change `command "java -jar <path to your file>/file.jar"`. The jar itself should not be part of the cookbook

Comment: You mean no need to copy the jar file inside cookbook . i need to copy the jar file inside my node in  any path and i have yml file as well.

Comment: i am getting this error  Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[run app.jar in directory]'

Comment: Please ask a new question with your recipe and someone will answer is quickly. Make sure to include details and formatting