# Writing custom Chef cookbook to install and run homegrown app

Tags: java, chef-infra, cookbook

I am new to [Chef](https://www.chef.io) and am trying to create a simple custom cookbook. I have an executable JAR that I have hosted on a private binary repo, and I'd like my cookbook to install this JAR, configure the server to be able to run the JAR, and then 
actually run it.

Specifically, I want the cookbook to:

- Download `http://myrepo.example.com/myapp.jar` to `/opt/myapp/bin` on the node; then
- Set `MYAPP_HOME` env var to `/opt/myapp/bin`; then
- Run `java -jar /opt/myapp/bin/myapp.jar --setup`

Obviously this cookbook depends on Java (ideally 8+) being installed on the server ahead of time.

Using this [excellent guide](http://www.devopsnotes.com/2012/02/how-to-write-good-chef-cookbook.html) as my starting point, here is my best attempt thus far:

#### Create the cookbook:

> knife create cookbook cookbook-myapp -o cookbooks/ -r md

#### `/cookbooks/cookbook-myapp/recipes/default.rb`:

```
package http://myrepo.example.com/myapp.jar

service "myapp" do
    action :install
end

env 'MYAPP_HOME' do
    value '/opt/myapp/bin'
end

bash 'run_jar' do
    code <<-EOH
    java -jar ${MYAPP_HOME}/myapp.jar --setup
    EOH
end
```

But this is obviously wrong. Any ideas or nudges in the right direction anyone can give me?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414090/how-to-run-a-java-program-at-background-from-chef-recipe/18418187#18418187

Answer (score 1):

```
remote_file '/path/to/myapp' do
  source 'http://myapp.repo.com/myapp.jar'
end

template '/etc/init.d/myapp.conf' do
  source 'myapp.init.config.erb'
  variables :home => '/opt/myapp/bin'
end

service 'myapp' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

and, of course, you'll need to write myapp.init.conf.erb in `cookbook/templates/default`.  That is your init script for running the app as a service, and includes the bash command and setting the environment variable.